# Use Azure Data Factory to move part of a database in sql azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to move about 40 tables from 1 instance of sql azure to another with azure data factory. The flow looks like this: [image: Azure Data Factory flow]

I run a stored procedure to disable to referential constraints between the tables, then I remove all of the existing data with delete statements. I iterate over the tables to copy with a @item().copyActivity.translator mapping and then reenable all of the constraints. However ids are not the same as in the source database and new ones are being created. Is there anyway of making the data exactly the same?

Edit:

I have amended the Copy trial foreach step to do the following, however I still get the same problem and it ignores the identity insert:

[image]

Comment: Assuming the ids are autogenerated on the destination DB then it sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077953/azure-data-factory-copy-identity-column-with-gaps.

Comment: I'll try their solution and let you know.

Comment: It's not quite the same as I am moving from sql azure to sql azure so the suggested solution uses a staging table whereas I don't see the point of this when I can cut out the middle man. I have amended the above

Comment: The link uses the staging table so that the final insert can occur in one transaction with the identity insert. I don't see anyway of doing what you're trying to do without using a staging table I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok but I've now done this. I switched off the constraint checking and then loop through each table switching on identity insert, inserted the data and then switching off identity insert. Slow but works without a staging table